# Api Platform 2 - Pass array of options to a custom encoder

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I am using API Platform 2.6

As I need to export some contents to PDF, I had to create a custom encoder for that to work.

#### 1st, I registered a new format, so I can request `application/pdf` content.

```
#File: config/packages/api_platform:
api_platform:
    ....
    formats:
        ....
        pdf: ['application/pdf']
```

#### 2nd, Created a `PdfEncoder` that extends `EncoderInterface`

```php
#File: src/Encodre/PdfEncoder.php:
class PdfEncoder implements EncoderInterface
{
    public const FORMAT = 'pdf';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly Environment $twig,
        private readonly Pdf $pdf,
    ) {
    }

    public function encode($data, $format, array $context = []): string
    {
        $content = $this->twig->render('pdf/template.html.twig', ['data' => $data]);
        $filename = sprintf('/tmp/%s.pdf', uniqid());

        $this->pdf->generateFromHtml($content, $filename);

        return file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    public function supportsEncoding($format): bool
    {
        return self::FORMAT === $format;
    }
}
```

#### 3d, on the resource, I created the appropriate call:

```php
#File src/Resource/MyResource.php
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'export' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '/myResource/{id}/export',
            'requirements' => ['id' => '\d+'],
            'output' => MyResourceView::class
        ],
    ],
)]
class MyResource
{
    public int $id;

    /** Other Attributes **/
}
```

As you can see, On the `PdfEncoder` class, I hard coded the path to the Twig Template,
But As I need to export other resources to PDF, and they are using different templates, I need to pass this template path as an option to the encoder, Maybe on the context variable would be great.

Here is what I am looking for.

```
#File: src/Encodre/PdfEncoder.php:
class PdfEncoder implements EncoderInterface
{
    ....

    public function encode($data, $format, array $context = []): string
    {
        $template = $context['export']['template']?? null;
        if (!$template){
            throw new \Exception('Twig template is not defined');
        }

        $content = $this->twig->render($template, ['data' => $data]);
        $filename = sprintf('/tmp/%s.pdf', uniqid());

        $this->pdf->generateFromHtml($content, $filename);

        return file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I tried adding that on the Resource, but ApiPlatform deleted them before having them on the context array

```php
#File src/Resource/MyResource.php
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'export' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '/myResource/{id}/export',
            'requirements' => ['id' => '\d+'],
            'output' => MyResourceView::class,
            'export' => [
                'template' => 'pdf/template.html.twig',
            ]
        ],
    ],
)]
class MyResource
{
    public int $id;

    /** Other Attributes **/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with so far,

This helps me to get the template name dynamically.

```php
#File: src/Encodre/PdfEncoder.php:
class PdfEncoder implements EncoderInterface
{
    public const FORMAT = 'pdf';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly Environment $twig,
        private readonly Pdf $pdf,
    ) {
    }

    public function encode($data, $format, array $context = []): string
    {
        $template = sprintf('pdf/%s.html.twig', lcfirst($context['output']['name']));

        if (!$this->twig->getLoader()->exists($template)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Missing template for %s', $context['output']['class']));
        }

        $content = $this->twig->render($template, ['data' => $data]);
        $filename = sprintf('/tmp/%s.pdf', uniqid());

        $this->pdf->generateFromHtml($content, $filename);

        return file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    public function supportsEncoding($format): bool
    {
        return self::FORMAT === $format;
    }
}
```

`$context['output']['class']` is the name of the View class (base name)
So this way, for every View, I have a twig file.

> I won't mark this answer as the solution as I think there might be nicer/recommended way to do that.